# Procedure for throttle body and idle air control replacement (ford ranger)

Tags: replace, ranger, throttle-body, iac-valve

I'll be replacing the throttle body in my 2004 Ford Ranger (engine v6 3.0L vin-U, mileage ~ 130000) as the result of my previous post (see here [Is hot desert weather the source of my recurring car problem?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45979/is-hot-desert-weather-the-source-of-my-recurring-car-problem?noredirect=1#comment79414_45979))

I was quoted $900 for the total cost. MSRP is $450 for this part, but I found it online for $280. Therefore I'm doin it myself.

I scoured youtube for instructions on TB replacement. I found information on the procedure for cars in general, and only one video specific to rangers.

My question is, are there any precautions or steps that mechanics take when replacing the throttle body? I'll also be replacing the idle air control at the same time since this was related to the original engine code (p0506), as discussed in the post linked above.

I noticed some folks wear latex gloves in these videos - is this just to keep stuff off their hands? Or is it because you have to be extra careful about letting any dust or residue into the system during the replacement?

Comment: Great question. I would bet this is just straight forward, but you'll most like need to adjust both the throttle position sensor and the IAC. I'm sure someone will answer this for you. The gloves are just keeping hands a little cleaner. Most people these days wear nitrile gloves because of latex allergies and because they just plain work a little better (and are pretty cheap). If you decide to get some, get the thicker 9mil versions as they last longer than the light duty (3mil) and medium duty (5 mil) ones (by a long shot).

Comment: Is this an electronic throttle body (no throttle cable)?

Comment: I would guess based on the existence of the IAC valve that only the IAC part is electronic.

Comment: The V6 in this Ranger has a [throttle position sensor](http://www.rockauto.com/info/154/TH198Tphoto%20primary__ra_p.jpg).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thank you for the insight! Nitrile 9 mil sounds like the way to go

Comment: @CharlieRB as Paulster2 said, for the V6 there's a throttle body and then there's a throttle body sensor (sold seperately $$).

Comment: @juhist I didn't realize the IAC is an electric component, thank you for the heads up

Comment: The reason I asked if it was electronic (no cable) was because they used servo actuated (no cable) throttle valves starting in 2004. It may or may not have had one. If it had one, there is a relearn procedure that needs to be done after replacement. Looks like you got the answer you need.

Comment: It is recommended you "reset the idle strategies" in the PCM after replacing these parts. Its fairly easy, disconnect battery for 15 minutes, connect battery, start the vehicle  (do not touch the steering wheel, brake pedal or gas pedal while doing this) AC-Heat is off prior to starting also, let idle without any disturbance for 15 minutes, reset is now finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, It's fairly straight forwards. If you have a funny idle after replacing the parts and it wasn't there before. Recheck for vacuum leaks. If none are found reset the Keep Alive Memory with a scantool.

Regarding your code I would try cleaning the IACV, throttle body and resetting the KAM first.

Gloves are personal preference. I wear them because working with chemicals and the constant hand washing all day, destroys my hands.

> Throttle Body
>
> Disconnect the battery ground cable. Remove the air cleaner outlet
>   pipe. Remove the bolt and the snow shield
>
> Fig 7: Removing Bolt And Snow Shield
>   [image]
>
> Disconnect the throttle position (TP) sensor electrical connector.
>
> Fig 8: Disconnecting TP Sensor Electrical Connector
>   [image]
>
> Disconnect the accelerator cable, the speed control cable and the
>   return spring.
>
> Fig 9: Disconnecting Accelerator Cable, Speed Control Cable And Return
>   Spring
>   [image]
>
> Remove the bolts and the throttle body.
>
> Fig 10: Removing Throttle Body [image]
>
> If necessary, install a new throttle body gasket.
>
> If necessary, remove the TP sensor.
>
> Fig 11: Removing TP Sensor [image]
>
> To install, reverse the removal procedure.

---

> IACV
>
> Disconnect the battery ground cable.
>
> Disconnect the idle air control (IAC) valve electrical connector.
>
> Fig 3: Disconnecting IAC Valve Electrical Connector
>   [image]
>
> Remove the IAC valve and discard the gasket.
>
> Fig 4: Removing IAC Valve And Discarding Gasket
>   [image]
>
> NOTE: Install a new IAC valve gasket.
>
> To install, reverse the removal procedure.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Question: are the torque measurements just a "heads up" for how difficult these various bolts will be to remove? Or should I be making sure to re-attach each bolt up to the torque values provided? If so, how would you measure this?

Comment: Not hard to remove at all, 89 inch pounds is not a lot of torque. The intake manifold is either aluminum or plastic. If you have one a 1/4" inch pound torque wrench to tighten to spec. It's not a huge deal if it's not exactly to spec on gaskets like the tb and iacv gaskets.

Comment: Thanks again, I nearly successfully installed the new throttle body and idle air control valve. All except reconnecting the battery, I started a new post to troubleshoot a strange problem I'm having with reconnecting the battery causing the horn to sound off (https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46522/ford-ranger-replaced-throttle-body-now-horn-wont-stop-honking). If you have any insight that would be greatly appreciated!