# Replaced throttle body - now horn won't stop honking

Tags: ford, battery, ranger, throttle, horn

This is the final question to my DIY ford ranger repair series. You can see the first two here: 
1) [Is hot desert weather the source of my recurring car problem](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45979/is-hot-desert-weather-the-source-of-my-recurring-car-problem)
2) [Procedure for throttle body and idle air control replacement ford ranger](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/procedure-for-throttle-body-and-idle-air-control-replacement-ford-ranger)
I have since replaced the throttle body, throttle body gasket, idle air control valve, and idle air control valve gasket. I followed the procedure as outlined by the kind folks in the second of the listed posts... Well, I followed all except the final step of reconnecting my battery.
The problem is that when I connect my battery back up (connecting positive first, then ground), the moment I touch the ground cable to the negative terminal **my car starts laying on the horn!**. Not just a honk, but a solid laying on the horn.

What I've done so far to troubleshoot:

- Cleaned all acid buildup off battery cables and terminals
- Checked that the connections removed during the throttle body replacement were both snapped in, and not backwards, specifically the:

  - throttle position sensor electrical connector
  - idle air control valve electrical connector
- Checked the three non-electrical cables connected to the throttle body

  - accelerator cable
  - speed control cable
  - return spring
- Checked that nothing was in the "on position" inside car (lights, wipers, ac/heat, etc)
- Checked the battery was not in backwards
- Replaced with new battery (was old anyways)
- I identified the horn fuse in the circuit box and I switched that circuit with one of its neighbors. But it still honks.
- **The last thing I have done** is I took the horn fuse out and connected the battery. No honking horn. **BUT** the door ajar chimed erratically, the passive anti theft system light (underneath my steering wheel) was blinking, along with a small clicking sound (like maybe the turn signal indicator).

I can't figure out what I did wrong!
car specs: 2004 ford ranger edge, v6, 3L, gas, vin u, 130000 miles

Comment: Glad it is resolved, but please do not add [SOLVED] to the title. This is not a forum. You did answer your own question with what fixed it. As soon as allowed, you should mark it as accepted. That will let others know there is a resolution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured it out. The issue was unrelated to the throttle body or any repairs I did.
The problem was because I completely removed my battery. Upon re-installing the battery, the cars passive anti theft system (PATS) was engaging. Strange, because I was never aware I had an alarm system. 
Solution:
1) remove car horn fuse
2) close door and lock
3) connect battery
 
4) open locked door with key
5) insert key in ignition.
Bingo, problem solved.

Comment: Wow, what a stupid design decision by Ford. Glad you figured it out!